# Required login session in dashboard for display in external application

Tags: drools, dashboard

I am using [dashboard](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/dashboard-builder) in my project and [integrated](http://docs.jboss.org/dashbuilder/release/6.1.0.Final/html_single/#chap-dashbuilder-integration) into another web application. But for displaying charts it requires a login session for dashboard. If not logged in, no charts will displayed.

How can I  display charts from dashboard with making any login?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill  How can i able to display charts from dashboard with making any login.

Comment: [edit] your question to add this information